# How to make my posts visible on the home index of my blog [Blogspot]?

Tags: html, css, blogger

The layout of my blog was initially an image portfolio type, so it wasn't supposed to have text. On the home page I would see a gallery. Many years later I have made many changes but only now I wanted to go back to seeing the text of the posts. I can only see the title. I tried to see one by one all the classes to see if there was something set to Display none. No luck. I'm starting to think it's just the layout programming that doesn't provide for what I'm asking for at all.
I can insert the blog link:
https://www.michelepetrelliart.com/search?

Not knowing where the problem is located I should have pasted the whole xml code of the blog. But I think it's too long.

Comment: The console of your blog displaying several dozens of errors like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')`, maybe cause by this?

Comment: No, those errors had nothing to do with it. I have some short texts that repeat and I put them on innerHTML.